# SQL Statment unkown column in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update fields in my database, everything is working fine. However, i am getting an error 'Error Code 1054. Unkown Column 'userCertificateID' in 'where clause' whenever i am trying to update the table data

```
CREATE TABLE `userCertificate` (
  `userCertificateID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificatename` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userCertificateID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


UPDATE userExperience 
SET certificatename = 'PMPPP' 
  , organization = 'hello' 
  , location = 'Canada' 
  , startdate = '2019-12-31' 
  , enddate = '2019-12-31'
WHERE userCertificateID = 4
```

In mysql it underlines organization and says "Organization is not valid in this position, expecting an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the wrong table, try :

```
UPDATE userCertificate 
SET certificatename = 'PMPPP' 
  , organization = 'hello' 
  , location = 'Canada' 
  , startdate = '2019-12-31' 
  , enddate = '2019-12-31'
WHERE userCertificateID = 4
```

Comment: any idea why i am getting a warning for organization though?

Comment: When I have this kind of error, I try to modify the syntax. I'm pretty sure it's because of the column name that can be confusing for MySQL but I'm not sure at 100%